# Animation Nodes Combining lists generated after several loop iterations

Tags: animation-nodes

I am iterating over a number of objects in a loop using animation nodes. Each iteration of the loop generates a list. How do I combine those lists into 1 final list of the same dimension. Each list is a Boolean List. Basically I want to Boolean "Or" each list till I get a final list. In the animation node tree below. I want to find the locations inside all objects. Not just the one that is currently being iterated over. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use *"reassign"* from the advanced settings:

[image]

Set the final list as parameter.

Select the loop node.

Go to the *"node"* tab, *"advanced node setting"*.

Check *"output"* to have the result as output.

Click on the *"reassign"* button: that will create an reassign output node that you can drag and place in the node tree.

Comment: Thanks very much I didn't realize Loop  had this flexibility .